# Designing tap-to-expand cell in storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have added a feature to my app that allows users to add notes which will appear in table view cells when they are tapped as they expand to show more content.

My question is - How do I layout the content that is to be shown when the cell is expanded? I have tried adding the textView to the prototype cell, but I just get the textView overlapping on the other cells in the table view rather than being hidden before being tapped.

Here is my code for when a cell is tapped:

```
var selectedRowIndex: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: -1, inSection: 0)

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedRowIndex = indexPath
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex.row {
        if cellTapped == false {
            cellTapped = true
            return 141
        } else {
            cellTapped = false
            return 70
        }
    }
    return 70
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the cell's clipToBounds property to YES (or select the "Clip Subviews" check box in IB for the cell), so none of its subviews will show outside the bounds of the cell. The text view should have constraints to the sides of the contentView as well as a height constraint. It should also have a constraint to something above it, and that view should have a constraint to the top of the contentView. The constraints should look something like this,

[image]

Comment: Setting 'Clip Subviews' to on works great, with the exception of swiping to delete. The textview overlaps the cell underneath it again.

Comment: Where to set  Clip Subviews @user3746428 ?